# inline SVG but in a separate file?

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to store SVG code in a separate file so I can clean up the main code.

I'm using this script in the `<head>`

```
 <script    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("icon").load("icon.xml");
    });
</script>
```

and I'm calling the file like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="/""><div id="icon"></div></a>
</div>
```

but nothing appears. This method is working for me for referencing as a separate html for nav links. Does this method not support other file types?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a solution, but the jQuery [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for that element would be `$("#icon")`.

Comment: XML or SVG? Also, there are multiple errors. Do you mean `$('#icon')`? Next, there is an extra double quote in `<a>` tag. Last, you should not nest `<div>` in `<a>`; use inline element like `<span>` instead.

Comment: @Raptor thanks, correcting all those errors fixed the problem. and also, I took the svg code and saved it as an xml file. I'm going to experiment to see if I can stylize the svg in css this way. thanks again

Comment: A modern native Web Component can make it a lot easier: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to typos, the SVG cannot be displayed. Here is the fix:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $("#icon").load("icon.xml");
    });
</script>
<div class="logo">
    <a href="/"><div id="icon"></div></a>
</div>
```